# How to convince Remmina to use two displays in a three monitor setup

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, opensuse, kde-plasma-5, remmina

I have two external monitors (both 1920x1200) connected to a laptop. I'm connecting to a Win10 (with also two monitors on its PC) via *Remmina*, with an `*.rdp` file supplied by *Citrix Netscaler Gateway*.

- Every application that's maximized in the session takes all the space of both the displays and
- centered dialogs/apps appear in the maximized center, i.e. are spread aside the physical middle of the two monitors.

That's bad.

1. Can I convince Remmina to consider the two monitor setup on the remote system so that maximizing inside the session just uses one of the local displays?
2. Can I convince Remmina to open new (centered) windows/dialogs centered on the first local display (without a *Window Rule* [see additional info below] for each and every)?
   [Solved implicitly if 1. is solved.]
3. If 1. and/or 2. isn't possible natively I have another idea:
   Can I connect with two sessions, one using the first remote display and one using the second?

There's a [image] *Multi monitor* button in Remmina's session toolbar. But it:

- does nothing when activated in full-screen mode,
- then scrambles my displays when switching from full-screen to windowed mode (and also back to full-screen mode)
  [image: Multi monitor activated and switching from full-screen to window]
- and even terminates the connection without further notice when activated in windowed mode.

### Additional information (for potential future seekers, readers, attempters)

At first I struggled to convince Remmina to take all space of both the external monitors  for the session (including/overlapping the space of the local bottom panel). I managed this via:

1. A Window Rule

   Created via *Right-click Remmina's title bar* ➔ *More Actions* ➔ *Configure Special Window Settings*.

   [image: System Settings ➔ Window Management ➔ Window Rules]
2. Session toolbar

   - [image] *Toggle fullscreen mode* (Default: <kbd>Right-Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, I changed that to <kbd>Scroll</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> since <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is standard for *Find* in so many applications).
   - [image] *Toggle dynamic resolution update*

Answer (score 2):

I found out (by try and error, not via web searches or in the [four-page[!, WTF?] User's guide](https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/wikis/Usage/Remmina-User%27s-guide)) that the [image] *Multi monitor* button in Remmina's session toolbar is ought to support exactly what I want: Maximizing windows inside the session to one display only.

So, apparently the screen scrambling and connection termination when using it is worth a bug report: [Using 'Multi monitor' mode scrambles displays or even terminates connection](https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/issues/3046).

#### UPDATE

I use [`xfreerdp`](https://www.mankier.com/1/xfreerdp) meanwhile, which is fine but brought up another issue: [*How to set a shell script as KDE file association*](https://superuser.com/q/1828467/516482).

For those who like to stick to Remmina and also face the "connection termination on multi-monitor toggle in windowed mode" issue here's what I always do to avoid it:

- Switch to fullscreen mode ([image]).
- Activate multi-monitor ([image]). Nothing happens/changes on the displays, just continue...
- Switch to windowed mode (t.b.d.).
- Switch to fullscreen mode again ([image]).
- Enjoy!

  (Well, at least partly here, since there are unused black ~1 cm stripes at top and bottom of my main display, which wastes space and also causes fonts to look craggy.)