# How to set a shell script as KDE file association

Tags: remote-desktop, file-association, opensuse, kde-plasma-5, tumbleweed

###### UPDATE

Disclaimer: Cross-posted to SUL (which I know is usually discouraged) [*How to set a shell script as KDE file association*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/768557/88374). Since with only 14 views and no response whatsoever within 3 days I do not have much hope here.

---

I'm connecting to a Win10 with an `*.rdp` file supplied by *Citrix Netscaler Gateway* via download in my FF.

I wrote a shell script that takes the `*.rdp` file as `$1` and it works in *Bash*:

```bash
...
set -x
xfreerdp "$1" /monitors:0,2 /floatbar:sticky:off,default:hidden,show:always /u:<me> /p:<...>
...
```

To be able to run this script from within GUI apps I created a new *File Association* with *Known Type*: *application/rdp* since `*.RDP`, `*.rdp` was assigned to *Remmina* before (and I removed these two from there):

[image: File Association RDP]

There's a `~/.local/share/applications/Bash-RDP.desktop`.

In FF I have set:

[image: FF Settings > Application > RDP]

But, this neither works when opening the downloaded `*.rdp` in FF's downloads drop-down or *Downloads Library* nor in my *Downloads* folder in *Dolphin*. If I do so *xfreerdp* appears in the taskbar with a progress circle for a few seconds only and without any further visual representation. And an *xfreerdp* task remains at every try which I have to kill afterwards.

#### UPDATE

This is strange. My old (working) *Known Type* `x-remmina` has now the *Filename Patterns* `*.rdpx`, `*.remmina`. (I mentioned above that I moved `*.RDP`, `*.rdp` from there to my new one.):

[image: x-remmina]

There's `xfreerdp` first in the *Application Preference Order* and **exactly this is taken** when selecting an `*.rdp` file, such ignoring my new known type, my associated filename patterns, my application preference and finally my script. How do I know? I changed the order to:

[image: Changed Application Preference Order]

and the `*.rdp` file opened in *Kate*.

Is this worth a bug report?

#### UPDATE 2

It was, for me: [*New custom Known Type in File Associations is ignored*](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=481035).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I achieved what I want by:

1. *File Associations* ⮕ *Know Types*: `rdp` ⮕ <kbd>－ Remove</kbd>
2. *Know Types*: `x-remmina` ⮕ *Filename Patterns* ⮕ <kbd>＋ Add</kbd>: `*.rdp` & `*.RDP`
3. *Application Preference Order* ⮕ <kbd>＋ Add...</kbd> ⮕ *Konsole*
4. Select *Konsole* ⮕ <kbd>️ Edit...</kbd> ⮕ *Application*:

   1. Program: `/bin/bash`
   2. Arguments: `/home/<user>/bin/rdp.sh %U`
5. Make sure that *Konsole* is at the top in *Application Preference Order*.
6. Enjoy!

#### UPDATE

If found that this has a drawback: When selecting *Konsole* from the system menu or bottom panel it appears on the bottom panel for less than a second and disappears. If I right-klick its icon and select *Open a New Window* or *... Tab* it opens normally.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the `-c` option. The parameter to that option is not a script *file* – the parameter *itself* is the script that will receive the remainder as $1, $2, etc. So what you have right now is one script (nameless) calling another script (rdp.sh), in which case the positional arguments are never "passed through" implicitly – that would only happen if `$1` or `$@` were used explicitly, e.g.:

```
Program: bash
Arguments: -c '~/bin/rdp.sh "$1"' -- %U
```

(You need to specify a dummy argument, such as the `--` here, because the first argument that follows will actually be stored in the special $0, not in $1.)

Usually, though, you can omit the whole `-c` option and have Bash directly run a script *file* as the original intention probably was:

```
Program: bash
Arguments: /home/gerold/bin/rdp.sh %U
```

(This is also *why* the first argument that follows is stored in the special $0 instead of becoming $1.)

This does lose the ability to use `~/`-expansion in arguments, but that's rarely an issue (if the .desktop file were shared between multiple users on the same system, then the script would be in /usr/bin anyway).

To simplify it even further, `chmod +x` your script (and make sure it has the usual `#!` header), then you'll be able to do:

```
Program: /home/gerold/bin/rdp.sh
Arguments: %U
```

In this case, `Program: rdp.sh` would be enough if your $PATH is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your "_don't use_ `-c`" hint looked very promising. I configured it accordingly but unfortunately the behaviour didn't change. See the update to my question for the probable cause.